# Set TextView style as TabLayout.Tab default style programmatically

Tags: android

I'm having issues with the following scenario:
   I do set a custom view to a TabLayout.Tab (not to all existing tabs) and I need that the customview attached to some tabs to be as same as a default tab.

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = retrieveTabAt(TAB_POS);
 TextView textview = new TextView(context);
 // modify the textview with needed info
 tab.setCustomView(textview);
```

Everything works perfectly and just fine, the only problem is that the default tab is a little bit bold and quite different and I need that textview to take the same effect/style.

I tried to set typeface to BOLD for the textview but it was too bold.

How can I make the custom textview look like a default tab ?

You can see below the differences :

[simple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGwi7.png)

and the one with bold set on textview :
[bold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2zYr.png)

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you're trying to match your custom view against?

Comment: Edited with pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a style for you tab like so:

```
<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

Add the values you want on the text appearance, eg.

```
<style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
 </style>
```

Then match the above values in the style of your custom textview